# Objective C Simple If Success

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

Hey everybody, whats the best way to apply the 'if success' method?
I'm trying this, but no luck.

```
BOOL success = false;

success = [self.view addSubview:carregandoView];
carregandoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
carregandoView.center = self.view.center;

if (!success)
{

 //stuff
}
```

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: `addSubview:` doesn't return anything. What do you want to check success of, exactly?

Comment: Could you be more clear about how this isn't working?

Comment: I just want cert myself if the view is already added.

Comment: `self.view == carregandoView.superview` although this doesn't make much since unless you do that check before adding the subview. UIKit does all of the adding view stuff for you and you can continue confidently knowing that your view has been added.

Comment: Is this a Cocoa or UIKit program? If it's UIKit then you can use the `:viewDidLoad` method -- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad

Comment: UIKit. But i cant see how this can help me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `addSubview:` doesn't return anything. Secondly, you can test if the subview has already been added like this:

```
if (carregandoView.superview != self.view)
    // do something
```

Thirdly, you can add a view to a superview only once (that is, sending `[self.view addSubview: carregandoView]` multiple times doesn't do anything besides bringing the subview to front), and you can use this trick to ensure the subview remains above its siblings.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the correct syntax.

Have you tried NSLog-ging/debugging and inspecting the value of success?
See related link [here](http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2010/04/objective-c-and-the-properties-of-bool/).

Also, it might be the case that

```
[self.view addSubview:carregandoView]
```

doesn't seem to return any value (is it a void function?)

Comment: The fact is that im doing this for a login view. When the user press the Login button, i want to put a loading view before it requests the data. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes its return type is `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use this type of coding style on methods that return a value, and a value that makes sense as a BOOLEAN.  addSubView does neither.  You need to find some other method, function, property or variable that tells you if what you consider to be a success is true.